# Silverlight - dynamic number of properties necessary for my scenario?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, dynamic, properties

What I have at hand is an application to help figure out how to clean a polluted site ( multiple pollutants) with a number of techniques. Naturally I would have a Technique class and a Pollutant class.

```
Class Pollutant
{
string name;
double baselineAmount;
double reduction goal
...
}

List<Pollutant> pollutantsList=new List<Pollutant>;

Class Technique
{
string name;
List <PerPollutantProperties> PollutantRelatedProperties=new List<PerPollutantProperties>();
...
}

Class PerPollutantProperties
{
string name;
double CurrentLoad=0;
double ReducedLoad=0;
...
}

List<Technique> techniquesList= new List<Technique>();

main()
{
Pollutant pollutant1 = new Pollutant();
Pollutant pollutant2 = new Pollutant();

...
pollutantsList.Add(pollutant1);
pollutantsList.Add(pollutant2);

Technique tec1=new Technique();
Technique tec2=new Technique();
tec1.name="tec1";
tec2.name="tec2";

PerPollutantProperties PPP= new PerPollutantProperties();    
PPP.name="Nitrogen";
tec1.PollutantRelatedProperties.Add(PPP);
tec2.PollutantRelatedProperties.Add(PPP);


PPP= new PerPollutantProperties();
PPP.name="Phorsphorus";
tec1.PollutantRelatedProperties.Add(PPP);
tec2.PollutantRelatedProperties.Add(PPP);

PPP= new PerPollutantProperties();
PPP.name="Sediment";
tec1.PollutantRelatedProperties.Add(PPP);
tec2.PollutantRelatedProperties.Add(PPP);

techniquesList.Add(tec1);
techniquesList.Add(tec2);
...

dataGridTechniques.ItemSource = techniquesList;
}
```

XAML:

```
         <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,483,0,0" Name="dataGridTechniques" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" RowHeight="55">
                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Current Load (lbs/yr)" Width="Auto">
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <toolkit:LayoutTransformer RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" >
                                        <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                        </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                        <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PollutantRelatedProperties}"  
                                                      RowHeight="70" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="25" Header="currentLoad">
                                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                                                <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                                </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentLoad,Converter={StaticResource MyDoubleToStringRoundConverter}}" />
                                                            </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="25" Header="Pollutant">
                                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                                                <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                                </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PollutantName}" />
                                                            </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                        </sdk:DataGrid>
                                    </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Reduced Load (lbs/yr)" Width="Auto">
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <toolkit:LayoutTransformer RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" >
                                        <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                        </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                        <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PollutantRelatedProperties}" 
                                                      RowHeight="70" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="25" Header="reducedLoad">
                                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                                                <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                                </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReducedLoad,Converter={StaticResource MyDoubleToStringRoundConverter}}" />
                                                            </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="25" Header="Pollutant">
                                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                                                <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                                </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PollutantName}" />
                                                            </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                        </sdk:DataGrid>
                                    </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                </sdk:DataGrid>
```

The tricky part is the application should allow a user to add/remove pollutants/techniques for consideration, and each technique has a different reduction efficiency for each pollutant. This means for each pollutant added, one more efficient need to be added to the Technique class. How should I structure the Technique class to accommodate this? I'd want to bind the techniquesList to something like a datagrid, where the user can enter customized information such as recuction efficient.

Edit: decided to go with a List (actually ObservableCollection per other posts and suggestion of RKaufman) property inside the Technique class, and nested Datagrid. So far I've run into two problems.

Problem 1. In addition to the columns I set up in XAML in the nested DG, each property of the data source shows up as a column as well. I initially had to set their visibility to "Collapsed" in the code behind, but when editing this post, I found out that I can simply set AutoGenerateColumns to False to get rid of the extra columns.

Problem 2. The TextBlock element in row 0 and column 0 of each and every of the nested Datagrid has the focus retangle around them. I wonder why and how to turn them off if possible. They don't disappear even if I click on other areas of the UI.

Screenshot (sorry not enough rep to embed image in the post yet):
http://xyk.iwebs.ws/nestedDG_textBlock_highlight.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying correctly you need to be able to add or remove pollutants to a technique. If that is correct then each technique need to have a collection of pollutants. To display this information to the user a datagrid with a row details template will solve that issue.
as for adding pollutants to techniques I would recommend you use a separate page or childwindow to add/edit the technique and use a couple of listboxes to select/deselect pollutants. 
I would also use System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection as opposed to a List as it implements INotifyCollectionChanged and will give notification to your UI when you add or remove items from the collections.

If this is incorrect let me know or give me some more information and I will try and guide you further.

Comment: RKaufman, I will look into row details template - currently I'm using nested datagrid (the one nested inside rotated by -90 degree), but I do have some issues that I had to find a workaround to resolve.

Comment: What issues did you have to work around I may be able to help. We do a considerable amount of complex data displays here.

Comment: RKaufman, I edited the original post since it allows better formatting. I realized what I need to do to resolve the first problem, but still not sure how to get rid of the focus retangles from appearing.